# Is it possible to interconnect 2 PC with Thunderbolt 3?

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-networking

As Thunderbolt 3 incorporates controller and has 40Gbits bandwidth, I believe it should be possible to link two PC with in a network.

I have an Intel NUC/Linux.

Comment: googling I found this: https://macperformanceguide.com/ThunderboltNetworking-SettingUp.html

Comment: I have got a intel NUC with thunderbolt 3, no Mac

Comment: so go here: https://superuser.com/questions/1244779/network-connection-over-thunderbolt-bridge-between-linux-and-mac In any case it lloks like it's a sort of 10GBE-over-thunderbolt so maximum is 10 gigabit/s

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it is possible, starting with linux 4.15 kernel and module thunderbolt-net over 2 thunderbolt3 devices and a dedicated cable.